# Object Creation for Multiple API Calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can an object be created with the help of which multiple API calls can be made? **For example**

- I have two APIs to call, namely:-

```
export const getCropDetails = (cropDetails, token) => API.get(`/crop?name=${cropDetails}`, {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "authorization": localStorage.getItem("token") }
});
```

```
export const getCropDetails = (cropDetails, token) => API.get(`/crop/details?name=${cropDetails}`, {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "authorization": localStorage.getItem("token") }
});
```

- Here I'm calling crops in the first and crop/details in the second.
- I want to know if a class can be written, such that I can access them anywhere, rather than calling them multiple times every time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```js
class MultipleAPI {
    constructor() {}
    async makeMultipleAPICalls() {
        const getCropDetailsOne = (cropDetails, token) =>
            API.get(`/crop?name=${cropDetails}`, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    authorization: localStorage.getItem("token")
                }
            });
        const getCropDetailsTwo = (cropDetails, token) =>
            API.get(`/crop/details?name=${cropDetails}`, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    authorization: localStorage.getItem("token")
                }
            });
        const results = await Promise.all([
            getCropDetailsOne,
            getCropDetailsTwo
        ]);
        return results;
    }
}

const h = new MultipleAPI();
console.log(h.makeMultipleAPICalls().then(res => console.log("res", res)));
```

Comment: Yes, something like this. But how would I call these? Can you give me an example by calling both using the class?

Comment: see inside the `console.log`, the method returns a promise, so the data is returned in the .then() block, that's how you call it.